# Redis BITCOUNT behavior

Tags: redis, bitmap, bit-manipulation

How does redis bitcount command work?

```
setbit test 1 1
setbit test 3 1
```

count bits.

```
bitcount test
```

returns **2**

Range count.

```
bitcount test 1 2
```

***returns 0***

Why? I thought I should get 1 for the bit position between 1 and 2, we have only one bit set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start` and `end` arguments refer to *bytes*. So you're asking for the number of bits in the second and third bytes of the string. You've only set bits in the first byte, so the answer is `0`.

It's unfortunate that the documentation for [`BITCOUNT`](https://redis.io/commands/bitcount) doesn't explain that, but it *is* mentioned in the documentation for [`BITPOS`](https://redis.io/commands/bitpos):

> It is possible to look for bits only in a specified interval passing the additional arguments *start* and *end*.... The range is interpreted as a range of bytes and not a range of bits, so `start=0` and `end=2` means to look at the first three bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that. Do you know how to get bits range?

Comment: @RamPrakash: I don't know of a built-in command to do it. You could write a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) that gets the corresonding byte range and then counts the specified bits.